# Replacing multiple strings with multiple strings in same column?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to replace multiple patterns in a string (column). The issue I'm having is with using str_replace. I list the string, the pattern to replace, and the replacement and it works with 1, but I can't seem to figure out how to replace multiple patterns (3) in the string. Each intended pattern has a specific replacement.

The three patterns I'm replacing start with the letter P, N, or G and I want to replace them with Positive, Negative, General.

What I have so far is:

```
spreadsheet.dat1<-spreadsheet.dat %>%
  mutate(domain=str_replace(column, "^P.*", "Positive"))
spreadsheet.dat2<-spreadsheet.dat1 %>%
  mutate(domain=str_replace(column, "^N.*", "Negative"))
spreadsheet.dat3<-spreadsheet.dat2 %>%
  mutate(domain=str_replace(column, "^P.*", "General"))
```

What I was hoping is that it would cumulatively add into the new column, domain, with the positive, negative, general all replaced by spreadsheet.dat3, but instead it only replaces w the current function.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you gave a small example dataset and then an example of what you'd like it turned into. I think what you're looking for is

```
spreadsheet.dat1<-spreadsheet.dat %>%
mutate(domain=case_when(str_starts(column, "P") ~ "Positive",
str_starts(column, "N") ~ "Negative",
str_starts(column, "G") ~ "General",
TRUE ~ NA_character_))
```

Comment: Since it's on a virtual desktop I can't copy paste but essentially the original column has various data named P01, P02, P03, etc, N01, N02, N03, etc, G01, G02, G03 etc and I wanted to change these all to Positive, Negative, General respectively.

What you posted is exactly what I was looking for (it worked)! Thank you so much!